# Trying to understand RC circuit with alternate voltage in LM3409 LED driver data sheet

Tags: mosfet, led-driver, constant-current

I've been working on designing a circuit that uses the shunt-FET approach documented in the [LM3409 data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3409.pdf?ts=1647968792511&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), wherein a MOSFET is place parallel to the LED load, and is driven by a PWM signal to control the brightness of the LEDs, rather than driving the PWM pin of the driver. The driver is a constant current buck converter that utilizes a constant off time to set the frequency of the regulating switch, and from what I can understand, that off time is determined by a resistor and capacitor. The time it takes for the resistor to charge the capacitor to a certain voltage (1.24V I believe), is what determined the off time of the cycle.

The datasheet includes a note about the possibility of the maximum off time occurring when the output is shorted when the shunt get is turned on by the PWM signal, and recommends using a second voltage and second resistor to prevent this from happening. What I am confused about is what exactly this second resistor is doing. Is it simply providing a minimal amount of current to ensure that the capacitor is charged in a minimum time? The formula the data sheet provides seems to indicate that the choice of resistor is related to the current output of the converter, so that is my best guess. I've included a screenshot of the relevant portion of the data sheet, and the entire thing can be accessed here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3409.pdf?ts=1647957494604&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.dk%252F. I specifically interested in what ROFF2 is doing in the circuit below, and what is being represented by the formula

ROFF2 = ROFF1 X VDD / ILED X RDSON

[image]

Comment: I still can't figure out why they short the LED out rather then stop producing current through the LM3409, seems like a waste

Comment: You avoid the delay involved in turning the driver on and off. Basically you can turn the LEDs on and off as fast as the MOSFET can. Allows very high frequency PWM.

Comment: When you short the LED, the output voltage from the constant current driver drops to just above zero - the actual value being Iled x Rds(on). As it uses this output voltage into COFF to set the off time of the buck converter, that off time will rise to its maximum and almost shut off the converter, i.e. doing exactly what you're trying to avoid by using the shunt FET. The extra voltage from Vdd via Roff2 stops that happening by keeping the converter running at a sensible off time.

Comment: That I can follow, but I'm wondering what the equation for calculating ROFF2 is indicating. Like what is the relationship there between ROFF2, ROFF1, VDD and the voltage VOUT when the output is shorted. Is it some version of V=IR? Or a voltage divider formula?

Comment: It's saying the ratio between Roff1 and Roff2 should be the same as the ratio between the nominal LED voltage (Iled x Rds(on)) and Vdd.

Comment: Awesome, that's super helpful, thank you so much!