# Shunt FET PWM best practices?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, driver, shunt

I am designing an LED driving circuit using an [AL8861Y-13](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL8861.pdf). Like any switching regulator, its PWM resolution/frequency are limited.

I want to do higher frequency and resolution, so I have opted for a shunt FET approach. I can't really find any good tutorials and guides on how to build this. There are some very specific applications for TI chips on the TI forums, but outside of that, if I search shunt dimming I'm mostly finding stuff about resistors.

Are there any good resources out there to read to help me design this? Otherwise maybe the kind people of this forum can critique this very bare bones implementation.

The one thing I know I have a question about is how to actually use PWM correctly here. It seems I either need to invert the PWM in software (which creates another problem where the LEDs will be full power at startup until the controller is running) or I need a way to invert it with some more components. Is there a "best practice" or some example circuit out there using any of these methods?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please follow EE best practices and draw positive voltages upwards, ground and negative downwards in your future schematics.

Comment: The obvious solution to inverting the signal is to use an inverter like a cd4069. Your first statement about switching regulators is incorrect. The AL8861 is working at 250kHz or so, so that is not your limitation. What pwm freq and resolution do you want/need?

Comment: The switching for the voltage regulation is up there, yes, I mean the dimming via external controller. It is limited to 10 bits at <500hz or equivalent. I would really like to get that up to 10kHz at 10 bits or more if possible. The problem at only 500hz is not visual but affects photography. From my understanding it's more to do with the charge in the inductor than the chip's design limitations, which is why most of these chips have similar limits, and why I decided I will need to go for a shunt FET.

Comment: It would probably be simpler to use constant voltage and use a n chan mosfet to switch the leds.

Comment: You might find the circuit in my question helpful https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/634714/173919  See also 8.3.8 "External Parallel FET PWM Dimming" of [TI datasheet LM3409](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3409.pdf?ts=1647968792511) and discussion in comments of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/613058/173919